# Wrong tenant in git azure devops repository - data factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am working in azure dtafactory with two environments for development and production. And I do automatic deployments through ARM templates. In development datafactory I am connected to azure devops git repository.

I have a problem and that is that the repository was registered with a tenant that should not have been.

How do I modify or move the repository to the correct tenant? would this affect the ARM template?

I am trying to connect a user that does not belong to the tenant that was left as owner of the repository. I cannot add the user as an external guest of the current tenant. That account already has all permissions and access to the azure devops repository that is connected to datafactory.
I think the solution is to change the repository tenant, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: use a new repo

According to [Switch to a different Git repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#switch-to-a-different-git-repository), we can disconnect to remove the association with the current Git repo. After you remove the association with the current repo, you can configure your Git settings to use a different repo in a new tenant and then import existing Data Factory resources to the new repo. Removing Git configuration from a data factory doesn't delete anything from the repository. The factory contains all published resources. You can continue to edit the factory directly against the service.

#### Solution 2: clone the old repo

If you want to keep the old repo history, you can [get the clone URL of the old Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022#get-the-clone-url-of-an-azure-repos-git-repo), then [import the repo to your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#import-into-a-new-repo) with the right tenant. After this, you can repeat the solution 1 to switch to the cloned Git repository.